# Bootstrap - Table border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables

I would like to know assign no border around the table, only at bottom(1px solid black) also at bottom of the head(same values). A part from this  I would like to assign color black at the cells of the table.

I am trying with this code but the result is wrong:

```
th {
    background: #dedee1;
    text-align: left;
}
.table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.table th{
    border: white solid 0px !important;
}
.table > thead > tr > th,
.table > tbody > tr > th,
.table > tfoot > tr > th,
.table > thead > tr > td,
.table > tbody > tr > td,
.table > tfoot > tr > td {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
.table > thead > tr > th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}
.table > caption + thead > tr:first-child > th,
.table > colgroup + thead > tr:first-child > th,
.table > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > th,
.table > caption + thead > tr:first-child > td,
.table > colgroup + thead > tr:first-child > td,
.table > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > td {
  border-top: 0;
}
.table > tbody + tbody {
  border-top: 2px solid #000000;
}
.table .table {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.table-condensed > thead > tr > th,
.table-condensed > tbody > tr > th,
.table-condensed > tfoot > tr > th,
.table-condensed > thead > tr > td,
.table-condensed > tbody > tr > td,
.table-condensed > tfoot > tr > td {
  padding: 5px;
}
.table-bordered {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.table-bordered > thead > tr > th,
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > th,
.table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th,
.table-bordered > thead > tr > td,
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td,
.table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.table-bordered > thead > tr > th,
.table-bordered > thead > tr > td {
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
table col[class*="col-"] {
  position: static;
  display: table-column;
  float: none;
}
table td[class*="col-"],
table th[class*="col-"] {
  position: static;
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}
.table > thead > tr > td.active,
.table > tbody > tr > td.active,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.active,
.table > thead > tr > th.active,
.table > tbody > tr > th.active,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.active,
.table > thead > tr.active > td,
.table > tbody > tr.active > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.active > td,
.table > thead > tr.active > th,
.table > tbody > tr.active > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.active > th {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.active:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.active:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.active:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .active,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.active:hover > th {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}
.table > thead > tr > td.success,
.table > tbody > tr > td.success,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.success,
.table > thead > tr > th.success,
.table > tbody > tr > th.success,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.success,
.table > thead > tr.success > td,
.table > tbody > tr.success > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.success > td,
.table > thead > tr.success > th,
.table > tbody > tr.success > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.success > th {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.success:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.success:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.success:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .success,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.success:hover > th {
  background-color: #d0e9c6;
}
.table > thead > tr > td.info,
.table > tbody > tr > td.info,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.info,
.table > thead > tr > th.info,
.table > tbody > tr > th.info,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.info,
.table > thead > tr.info > td,
.table > tbody > tr.info > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.info > td,
.table > thead > tr.info > th,
.table > tbody > tr.info > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.info > th {
  background-color: #d9edf7;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.info:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.info:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.info:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .info,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.info:hover > th {
  background-color: #c4e3f3;
}
.table > thead > tr > td.warning,
.table > tbody > tr > td.warning,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.warning,
.table > thead > tr > th.warning,
.table > tbody > tr > th.warning,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.warning,
.table > thead > tr.warning > td,
.table > tbody > tr.warning > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.warning > td,
.table > thead > tr.warning > th,
.table > tbody > tr.warning > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.warning > th {
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.warning:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.warning:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.warning:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .warning,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.warning:hover > th {
  background-color: #faf2cc;
}
.table > thead > tr > td.danger,
.table > tbody > tr > td.danger,
.table > tfoot > tr > td.danger,
.table > thead > tr > th.danger,
.table > tbody > tr > th.danger,
.table > tfoot > tr > th.danger,
.table > thead > tr.danger > td,
.table > tbody > tr.danger > td,
.table > tfoot > tr.danger > td,
.table > thead > tr.danger > th,
.table > tbody > tr.danger > th,
.table > tfoot > tr.danger > th {
  background-color: #f2dede;
}
.table-hover > tbody > tr > td.danger:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr > th.danger:hover,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.danger:hover > td,
.table-hover > tbody > tr:hover > .danger,
.table-hover > tbody > tr.danger:hover > th {
  background-color: #ebcccc;
}
.table-responsive {
  min-height: .01%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: why you want to change in bootstrap.css , just put your css in new file and make it is !important .

Comment: How? I do not understand.

Comment: !important is not necessary if you load your css after bootstrap css. Aniway which classes assigned to the table?